# URLs path vs page

Tags: url

Is there any consensus on the best practice of path vs page url structures (for simple, relatively static sites), in terms of usability and SEO?

e.g.

http://mysite.com/about.html

vs

http://mysite.com/about/

*Where the about folder contains index.html*

It would seem in terms of usability, esp. sharing and linking, that the path approach is much better (predicated upon the approach of only sharing the url up to the slash after the folder, and not including the index.html), albeit more complex in terms of organization -  and that the page approach is better for SEO.

Also I've never quite understood the difference between

http://mysite.com/about/

and

http://mysite.com/about/index.html

Will the first always redirect to the second, therefore slowing things down? And when sharing the first type of url, should/must one always include the slash?

Thanks

Comment: I'd argue against the `.html`, `.php`, `.aspx`, etc. extensions. They serve no purpose for the end user. As for redirection, no, not really. The webserver won't redirect the user. It'll just serve `index.html` when you request `/about/`.

Comment: if you avoid having the actual file name in the url then you're free to change the backend system as you please, without breaking URLs or making things unnecesarily complicated

Comment: @Blender - it's not just an extension, they're two different things, /about.html in the root vs /about/index.html. You can't not have the extension in the first case.

Comment: sometimes it is convenient for people to include content-type into the url, to simplify api usage e.g., .json, .xml. Other suffixes such as .php, .aspx are an implementation detail, no need to expose it to the users

Comment: @Perro you mean then you can just deal with folder names, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Let's think of it in an all-html context.

Comment: will mysite.com/about without the ending slash - when mysite.com/about/index.html exisits - cause a re-direct, and will it lead to the desired page?

Comment: @Ursinus, exactly. If you have `/about.html` and then change to use PHP you will have `/about.php`, breaking the old URL. If you have `/about/` the url will remain the same because you just change the `index.html` file to `index.php`

Comment: the redirects are mostly internal to the webserver, it's not going to reload the page (unless you really want it to)

Comment: @PerroAzul With 2 minutes to change an Apache configuration file, the URL `/about.html` can map to `/about.php`, `/content.php?page=about`, or whatever you want.

Comment: @IMSoP yes, it can be done but i'd rather avoid it

Comment: So the consensus seems to be the path approach is better for link sharing, doesn't cause redirects, and makes changes perhaps easier. I assume that it's worse for seo though, that the filename has more value than the folder name.

Comment: @Ursinus: There are really no redirects and there are no folders. You're telling the webserver, "send me the resource located at `/about/`". From there, it's *entirely* up to the webserver to determine what `/about/` is. You could have an `about` folder with an `index.html` file in there and that's what the webserver will serve. You could forward the request to a web framework and that'll handle what `/about/` does. It's entirely up to the server and assuming a that every website follows the folder structure just won't be correct.

Comment: but /about/ will return nothing if all that exists is /about.html - that was my point, in that context they are different things and the extension is required

Comment: @Ursinus: Not necessarily. It's simple to make `/foo/` map to `/foo.html`. Your question was about which structure is "better", and I'm saying that the simpler one is better. It exposes less useless information.

Comment: Can you share that method. Would be great. Thanks. I actually prefer just having all my html pages in the root since my site is pretty simple. It would be nice to share using the sans-extension method. Just to be clear, if I employ your method, I can have /foo.html in the root, share /foo only, and the user will get /foo.html (and other existing links written as /foo.html will still work OK)? Thanks

Comment: In this scheme would typing /foo.html in the address bar to invoke the page present as /foo when the page was loaded, and would following an internal link (i.e. from my nav) that was written with the extension present in the address bar without the extension? Thanks

Comment: Silly me, I didn't realize that all browsers are already doing this (don't have Safari to check, but everything else). I apologize for wasting anyone's time, but I still learned from the responses. Thanks to all for the input. Appreciated.